# using javascript how can I get how far down a page you are on an ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad

I have a page where I use jquery scrollTop() to determine how far down the page you are. Tbis works fine on all desktop borwsers, but however this has stopped working with ios 8.1.

I have tried $('body').scrollTop() and $(document).scrollTop() on all other browsers we get the actual x location. However on ipads you get 0 so my question is does anyone know of another way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the user agent and use `window.scrollTo` instead for ios devices. More info @ http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/?p=134